# How to get time part from SQL Server 2005 datetime in 'HH:mm tt' format

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, time

How to get time part from SQL Server 2005 datetime in `HH:mm tt` format

E.g.

```
11:25 AM
14:36 PM
```

Comment: how come you need AM/PM in HH:mm format?

Comment: Looks like something that will be easier to do in your application code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way is:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

If you have a look at [Books Online here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), format 100 is the one that has the time element in the format you want it in, it's just a case of stripping off the date from the front.

Comment: This will print 8:00 PM, but I think the question is looking for 20:00 PM

Comment: @Andomar - good point. If that is really what is needed, I'd argue the AM/PM is irrelevant and suggest a more conciser approach though

Answer (score 8):

You'll need two converts, one to get the HH:mm time, and one to get AM/PM.  For example:

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = '20:01'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @date, 108) + ' ' +
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @date, 100),18,2)
```

This prints:

```
20:01 PM
```

In a select query, replace @date with your column's name.

Comment: I would replace the SubString() and Convert() with a single DatePart() and Case-Statement.  This will also give you greater control over the casing/capitalization of your AM/PM.  i.e. (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 12 THEN 'am' ELSE 'pm' END)  You could also include the space in ' am' and ' pm' so you have one less concatenation as well.

Answer (score 7):

**SQL Server 2008**

```
SELECT
CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

**Result**

```
HourMinuteSecond: 13:06:56.5770000
DateOnly:         2012-07-26
```

**SQL Server 2000/2005**

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT
CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

**Result:**

```
HourMinuteSecond: 13:06:56.5770000
DateOnly:         2012-07-26
```

SQL Server 2000/2005

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 114),1,5)
```

resault : 22:05

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CONVERT` function:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, yourdatetimefiled, 114) AS [HH:MI(12H)]
```

Comment: According to MSDN, 114 = `hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)`.

Comment: but I want in HH:mm tt format and it does not provide tt info like AM or PM

Comment: I wrote the answer by heart since I don't have MSSQL access at the moment. I believe AdaTheDev got it right.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(getdate() as time)) [time],
```

Comment: SQL Sevrer 2005 does not support `Time` type, so this answer is totally false.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an actual datetime and not varchar

```
CAST(LEFT(YOURDATETIME,12) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS YOURNEWDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select right(convert(char(20),getdate(),0),7)
```

No check though

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012 and above use this:

`SELECT Format(GetDate(), 'hh:mm tt')`