# Get Time from Getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

I would like to take the `Getdate()` results of,

for example

```
2011-10-05 11:26:55.000
```

into

```
11:26:55 AM
```

I have looked other places and found

```
Select RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100),7)
```

which gives me

```
11:26AM
```

It's so close I can taste it!

Comment: Are you looking for a string representation in this specified format?

Comment: does the requirement dictate you not being able to fix this in code?

Comment: If you need this value as a TIME then I'd use the DATEDIFF answer from @Wil.  If this really is about formatting strings, then I'd recommend you do that outside of SQL, such as in your client application.

Comment: I will resign myself to this being a limitation of SQL (a silly formatting issue, but all the same) I will go ahead and do it in php.

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 30):

```
select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108)
```

returned `17:36:56` when I ran it a few moments ago.

Comment: Ah damn.. so close but no cigar.

Comment: That's better, but I require the AM/PM.

Comment: else can use 'convert(time, getdate())' return that answer.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201432/how-to-get-time-part-from-sql-server-2005-datetime-in-hhmm-tt-format) old thread.

If you can omit AM/PM portion and using SQL Server 2008, you should go with the approach suggested [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/)

To get the rid from nenoseconds in time(SQL Server 2008), do as below :

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE()) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: If you're converting it to varchar, it will no longer be datetime. Please check this [link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/13/format-date-sql-server.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to make a cast from date to time?

`select cast(getdate() as time)`

Reviewing the question, I saw the 'AM/PM' at end. So, my answer for this question is:

`select format(getdate(), 'hh:mm:ss tt')`

Run on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and Later.

Comment: this is a comment and not an answer

Comment: If you try to run this code you will see an answer and not a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo,  forgot about the format function.

Answer (score 3):

To get the format you want:

`SELECT (substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),22),10,8) + ' ' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),22), 19,2))`

Why are you pulling this from sql?

Comment: I hope to have a clock in php pulling time that is "live" but pulled from sql. (I'm using sqlsrv)

Comment: You are much likely better off, from many perspectives, doing the formatting in PHP then.  Let your SQL be about data and move the DATE and/or TIME values around as real values, not strings.  Keeping your data and your presentation separated is very good form.

Comment: @Dems, I considered this, and can and have done this in the past, but I need it to come from my computer, not the computer viewing it.

Comment: @Newkidirus you mean you need the time on the SQL box not the PHP box?

Comment: @Newkirirus - You mis-understand me.  Use GetDate() to get the date from the SQL server by all means.  But then format it as a string in PHP.  SQL *can* format, but it isn't designed *for* formatting, it's for *data*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)
```

Just try a few moment ago

Answer (score 0):

If it's SQL Server 2005 there is no `TIME` datatype. The easiest way to get only the time component is to set the date to 1/1/1900.

```
DECLARE @time DATETIME

SET @Time = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,@time,'1/1/1900'),@time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the time using below query:

```
select left((convert(time(0), GETDATE ())),5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datapart to maintain time date type and you can compare it to another time.
Check below example:

```
declare @fromtime time = '09:30'
declare @totime time
SET @totime=CONVERT(TIME, CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()),':', DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())))
if @fromtime <= @totime 
begin print 'true' end
else begin print 'no' end
```