# How to get the last one hour in format 'hhmmss' or 'hh:mm:ss' in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need how to get the last one hour in format 'hhmmss' in sql server
for example if the time now is 10:48:22 i need the expected result be 9:48:22

the time now -1

Comment: What do you mean "last one hour", give some examples of current time vs time you expect

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664608/get-time-from-getdate helps

Comment: i mean if the time now is 10:46:22 i need the result is 9:46:22

Comment: TRY `SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR,-1,'10:46:22'))` @LamisAlaa

Comment: @KillerQueen thanks alot it works

Comment: Glad that i could help :) @LamisAlaa

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** that you mean you want the time for the current hour (so for me right now, its 09:39 so you want `'090000'`) then this would get what you're after:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,'20000101',GETDATE()),'20000101'),14),':','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```
select convert(varchar(8), cast(dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) as time))
```

However, I you can probably also leave the value as a `time` rather than converting to a string.