# How to get time part from GetDate() As hh:mm tt in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is not duplicate of [How to get time part from SQL Server 2005 datetime in 'HH:mm tt' format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201432/how-to-get-time-part-from-sql-server-2005-datetime-in-hhmm-tt-format)

be cause all answers of that question returns 12:06PM (without space and need space)

I am trying to get only time part from SQL `GETDATE()`

and I am trying

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

but it is returning

```
12:06PM
```

I need  12:06 PM (Space before AM or PM)..

search a lot but failed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get time part from Sql Server 2005 datetime in HH:mm tt format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201432/how-to-get-time-part-from-sql-server-2005-datetime-in-hhmm-tt-format)

Comment: @samikuhmonen  this is not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201432/how-to-get-time-part-from-sql-server-2005-datetime-in-hhmm-tt-format, and mentioned the reason

Comment: Usually formatting should not be done on the DB layer, but on top of that. Is there a specific reason for doing it in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108) + ' ' + 
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9),2)
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7540/2377

Answer (score 7):

For SQL 2012 above:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'h:mm tt', 'en-US')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)),'PM',' PM'),'AM',' AM')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT substring(CONVERT(varchar(20), GetDate(), 9), 13, 5) + 
       ' ' + 
       substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

After A lot Practice Shortest Answer I Get..

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), 
              STUFF(RIGHT( 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100 ) ,7),
              6, 0, ' '))
```

Thanks All

Comment: For SQL 2012 or above, you can use `FORMAT()`

Answer (score 0):

**FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'h:mm tt', 'en-US')**

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.